# How can I set a post value without using a form in PHP?

Tags: php, post

I'm gathering data about users who visit my website using PHP. The way it works is by redirecting to a page that includes a script that collects information about the user. Then, that page redirects back to the page they came from. I just want to know how to set a POST variable for the original page that tells it that the collection is completed, to avoid a redirect loop. The code on the original page is:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['userdata'])) {
        //The data collection has completed
    } else {
        header("Location: /datacollector.php");
    };
?>
```

And the code on /datacollector.php is

```
<?php
//code to collect data is here
//code to redirect back to original page with $_POST['userdata'] set to true or something here
?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you ok with jQuery? And are you you ok with using Ajax or do you want to redirect? Sounds like you might cause a recursive race condition by redirecting to php and then redirecting back to the page.

Comment: How is it collecting data? Is the user aware? Can you just send the data via ajax and not have and redirect?

Comment: I would prefer PHP because I want to save the results to a database.

Comment: PHP is server side code, AJAX is the client-side language you'd use to communicate to the PHP with

Comment: How would I do this using AJAX?

Comment: I'll submit an answer with a basic example.

Comment: Don't use AJAX for this. Use header() function or cURL.

Comment: @PavelDenisevich Why?

Comment: @GarySchreiner AJAX is client side stuff. You will be surprised if client has disabled Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To create a POST request, open a up a TCP connection to the host using `fsockopen()`, then use `fwrite()` on the handler returned from `fsockopen()` with some kind of these values from this example that uses `header()` function:

```
header("POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
header("Host: $host\r\n");
header("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
header("Content-length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n");
header("Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
header($data);
```

Or just try to use the code above with `header()` function.
Alternatively, you can use cURL library.

Comment: AJAX is client side stuff. You will be surprised if client has disabled Javascript.

Comment: Your solution will create a POST request from the server, which runs the PHP, to the same server. To get data from the user, he has to accomplish some kind of client-side function. He's currently wanting to direct the user to another php page, collect whatever data, and then redirect them AGAIN back to the main page. He doesn't say what type of data he's trying to collect, but I don't see your answer accomplishing this.

Comment: Additionally, if they have javascript disabled (unlikely), he'll have a hard time getting any data from them aside from what's already in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it behind the scenes. Use jQuery post (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to send data to a php file on the back end.

html javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/scripts/processData.php',
      data: { 'value1' : 'valueIwanttosend' }
    });
  }
</script>
```

processData.php:

```
<?php

$value1 = $_POST['value1'];

// do database ops with the value

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to use `post` without `form`'s since it is not so maintainable and readable. Unless you use `ajax`.

But I guess what you actually want is not not using `form` element in your html but not showing it. In that case you can use hidden fields of a form to pass data without showing it to the client.

```
<form name="myform" action="yourAction.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="NoOneCanSee" value="whatever">
</form>
```

Comment: It's possible using header() function or cURL.